# Getting html elements from area

Tags: c#, html

Is there any way to get html source (of all elements) from browser in chosen area (**rectangle**)?
There is **`WebBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint`**, but it would mean, i have to loop through the whole document...

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you mean a chosen area? Chosen how?

Comment: Have you looked into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this .. for getting all elements in current document

```
   // start an instance of IE
public SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass ie;
ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
ie.Visible = true;

// Load a url
Object Flags = null, TargetFrameName = null, PostData = null, Headers = null;
ie.Navigate( url, ref Flags, ref TargetFrameName, ref PostData, ref Headers );

while( ie.Busy )
{
  Thread.Sleep( 500 );
}

// get an element from the loaded document
mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass document = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)ie.Document);
document.getElementById("myelementsid");
```

Comment: I meant something like document.getElementsFromArea(new Rectangle(0,0,100,100)));